# How to use mysql query using group by to find all the UNIQ titles used for the group

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following dataset

```
Id  Title   Group
1   title1    A
2   title2    A
3   title3    A
4   title4    A
5   title1    B
6   title2    B
```

I want query which returns following `result`

```
Group  Title
A      title1, title2, title3, title4
B      title1, title2
```

Is it possible using `GROUP BY` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT
  `group`,
  GROUP_CONCAT( title )
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `group`
```

btw you might want to consider renaming your "group" column as that's a reserved word in MySQL. It will still work but you will need to quote it with backticks every time you use it.

Answer (score 1):

use `distinct` with `group_concat` for unique titles:

```
SELECT `group`,GROUP_CONCAT( distinct title ) as titles
FROM tablename
GROUP BY `group`
```

Comment: thanx :) i like use of distinct